# Multivalue parameter in ssrs and mysql

Tags: mysql, ssrs-2008

I am using SSRS2008R2 to report data stored in MySQL database.

Due to MYSQL extension does not support multivalued parameters to be passed, it is suggested on the forums to use the syntax below.

="Select * from projects where projectID in (" + join(Parameters!Project.Value,",") + ")"

this is the query expression for a dataset. but when I try to run this, I get;

### Error during processing of the CommandText expression of dataset ‘Projects’. (rsQueryCommandTextProcessingError)

### Cannot set the command text for dataset 'Projects'. (rsErrorSettingCommandText)

An error has occurred during report processing. (rsProcessingAborted)

it is clearly an expression editor issue I guess rather than the query.

Could anyone tell me what is wrong with this query please?

Thanks for your help.

Regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you're missing the single quotes around the query

="Select * from projects where projectID in ('" + join(Parameters!Project.Value,"','") + "')"

That should do it